# Web page not found in web scraping, how can I find it in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've been working with R for about a year and love it. I've gotten into text mining recently and have had some difficulty. I'm trying to create a data frame with information from a website. I've been scraping the data and have been able to create two variables successfully. In attempting to create the third variable its not working. When I view the table that I've made, the content for that variable says "Sorry webpage cannot be found." But, I know its there! Any thoughts? Thanks everyone!

```
link = "https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjdt_665385/zyjh_665391/"
page = read_html(link)
```

```
title = page %>% html_nodes(".newsLst_mod a") %>% html_text()
slinks = page %>% html_nodes(".newsLst_mod a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.fmprc.gov.cn", ., sep = "")
date = page %>% html_nodes(".newsLst_mod span") %>% html_text()
```

Somewhere here is where I run into trouble... I get 'p' when using Selector Gadget and put that in the html_ nodes function...however, this doesn't seem to work and I'm coming up empty. If I adjust the scraping a little on the page, it might have nothing on the table when I view it.

```
get_s = function(slinks) {
  speeches_link = read_html(slinks)
  speech_words = speeches_link %>% html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(speech_words)
}
```

[What the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYYHL.png)

```
words = sapply(slinks, FUN = get_s)
```

```
speeches = data.frame(title, date, words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

The link that you need to paste in each URL is `https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjdt_665385/zyjh_665391`.

Try the following -

```
library(rvest)

slinks = page %>% html_nodes(".newsLst_mod a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% trimws(whitespace = '\\.')  %>% 
  paste0("https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjdt_665385/zyjh_665391", .)

get_s = function(slinks) {
  speeches_link = read_html(slinks)
  speech_words = speeches_link %>% html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(speech_words)
}

words = sapply(slinks, FUN = get_s)
words
```

Comment: Hey there! I very much appreciate your reply, it has been helpful. However, I'm still running into some trouble here. When I run the code, the head of the text appears in the console. However, there are texts of 40 speeches that I'm trying to put into my data frame. When I attempt to create the data frame with all three variables, I am encountering an error. The error implies that I have differing numbers of rows. Is there a way to get the text of all 40 speeches?

Comment: > speeches = data.frame(title, date, words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Error in data.frame(title, date, words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40, 6

Comment: I was testing the function so used only 6 values with `head`. I removed it now and you should be able to get all the text.

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah! I can now see the text from all 40 speeches in my console. However, when I runspeeches = data.frame(title, date, words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) I get this:  Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't get any such error on my side.